# Error on data descryption: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array at CryptorEngine.Decrypt

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I decrypt data error comes

> System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.    at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)    at
>   CryptorEngine.Decrypt(String cipherString, Boolean useHashing)

plese help me

ALSO I use  `replace(" ","+")`, `replace(" ","")` and use `trim()` but not solve problem

---

Question = CryptorEngine.Decrypt(Question, true);

---

```
   public static string Decrypt(string cipherString, bool useHashing)
    {

        if (cipherString == "")
            cipherString = " ";

        byte[] keyArray;   


        byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);           

     //Above line errors comes
```

Comment: Please show your work.. People can't read your mind.

Comment: I'm afraid SO doesn't issue crystal balls, so please show your code.

Comment: Where did you get your `cipherString`? If it comes from an encryption method, please show us the implementation of that method

Comment: Actually I pass cipherstring Question ----- Question = CryptorEngine.Decrypt(Question, true);

Comment: Is `cipherString` base64 encoded? If not, try encoding it first.